# SQLite - select row by year only?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I select rows from a table by year only?

```
SELECT * FROM speckdata AS s WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s.localdate, '%Y') = '2014')
```

I could get the result in `MySQL`

Now on `sqlite` I get this error,

> SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: SELECT*
>                 FROM speckdata AS s
>                 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s.localdate, '%Y') = '2014') [ near ")": syntax error ] Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE Exception Message: Component
>   returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
>   [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

If I change it to,

```
WHERE DATE(s.localdate, '%Y') = '2014'
```

It return no result.

BTW, the `localdate` is in date-time format such as **2014-10-09 14:59:53**

Comment: `SELECT * FROM speckdata AS s WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s.localdate, '%Y') = '2014'`

Comment: Are you sure you have `2014` year in `localdate`?

Comment: it is in date-time format such as 2014-10-09 14:59:53

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM speckdata AS s WHERE strftime('%Y', s.localdate) = '2014'
```

Answer (score 6):

Since DATE_FORMAT wouldn't work, maybe you can try an alternative solution

```
SELECT * FROM speckdata AS s WHERE DATE(s.localdate) LIKE '2014%'
```

P.S. You called DATE instead of DATE_FORMAT in your edit, I don't know it's intended or an accident on you.